# std::set of unique ptr range insert

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have 2 data structures which hold a set of unique_ptr like so

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entity>> tmpEnts;
std::set<std::unique_ptr<Entity>> tmpSet;
```

I am trying to perform an insert as shown below but i get errors when i compile. I am new to smart pointers.

```
tmpSet.insert(tmpEnts.begin(), tmpEnts.end());
```

tmpEnts is actually a simplification, it actually resides in a `std::map<uint, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entity>>> entities`

**EDIT**

The error is takes up a lot of space but i think there's something here which I don't really understand yet.

```
/home/evgen/workspace/test/ecs/src/entity_manager.cpp:41:22:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Entity; _Dp = std::default_delete<Entity>]’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/memory:80:0,
                 from /home/evgen/workspace/test/ecs/src/entity.hpp:4,
                 from /home/evgen/workspace/test/ecs/src/entity_manager.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:388:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
```

Comment: wild guessing I assume that your compiler tries to `.insert()` the range using copying, which is forbidden in case of perfoming it on `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: yea I had a similar thought, and i tried using the std::move. got the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tmpSet.insert(tmpEnts.begin(), tmpEnts.end());
```

is trying to copy elements from the `vector` to the `set`. That fails to compile because `unique_ptr` is not copyable, it must be moved. You can move the elements by using [`move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator)s instead.

```
tmpSet.insert(
    std::make_move_iterator(tmpEnts.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(tmpEnts.end()));
```

Note that after the above call, each `Entity` object in your `vector` will have been moved from.

Comment: yes im aware of exclusive ownership that unique_ptr does. i didn't know about make_move_iterator. thanks a lot! :D it works

Comment: Yes. `use of deleted function 'unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr&)'` "Thou shalt not copy unique_ptr"

Comment: Didn't he fall anyways? haha

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me say that if you are planning of moving these pointers around, `unique_ptr` is not the preferred way to go, but rather `shared_ptr`.

Second, `unique_ptr`-s cannot be just inserted into an adt. They have to be moved. So in order for your code to work, you have to use `std::move` semantics:

```
std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>> tmpSet;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    tmpSet.insert(std::move(std::make_unique<int>(1)));
    tmpSet.insert(std::move(std::make_unique<int>(2)));
}
```

Or, when moving from one adt to another:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> tmpEnts;
std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>> tmpSet;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    tmpEnts.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<int>(1)));
    tmpEnts.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<int>(2)));

    auto from = std::make_move_iterator(tmpEnts.begin());
    auto to = std::make_move_iterator(tmpEnts.end());
    tmpSet.insert(from, to);
}
```

Comment: that part i figured out what i was saying is when i am using the iterator of the vector to copy data to the set, is where i am getting lost.

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko, I have added the missing implementation for copying data from the vector to the set.

Comment: yea i didn't know about std::make_move_iterator. I'm relatively new to c++ as well but not new to programming. started learning c++ by building a simple 2d engine. currently implementing my ecs architecture. Thanks for your answer :)